# Magento Expo Las Vegas 2015

Tags: magento-enterprise

Is the Magento expo geared towards potential new customers or is mainly for programmers and designers?

Answer (score 4):

[Imagine Commerce 2015](http://imagine2015.magento.com/), previously known as Magento Imagine, is for everyone in the Magento and eBay Enterprise ecosystem. Enterprise customers and prospects have plenty of the event's programming directed at them, but there is always *a lot* of content and value for *anyone* in the Magento ecosystem including independent shops and developers, all the way up through enterprise-class business.

Notably the ecosystem itself creates a number of events which provide learning & networking opportunities:

- [Pre-Imagine Hackathon](http://www.eventbrite.com/e/pre-imagine-magehackathon-2015-las-vegas-tickets-15538891242) for developers
- [Pre-Imagine 5k](http://www.wagento.com/blog/magento-pre-imagine-race-2015.html), a nice little run before the event (glad it's not another desert run!)
- [Pre-Imagine](http://pre-imagine.com/) networking event, a community-sponsored pre-party (a tradition since the first Imagine)

Source: attended all but one Imagine